# I can't compile my contract. What's wrong with this fallback function?

Tags: solidity, fallback-function

```
function () payable external {
    address impl = methodsImplementations[msg.sig];
    require(impl != address(0x00), "Method not found. 404");
    
    assembly {
        let p := mload(0x40)
        calldatacopy(p, 0x00, calldatasize)
        let result := delegatecall(gas, impl, p, calldatasize, 0x00, 0x00)
        let size := returndatasize
        returndatacopy(p, 0x00, size)
        
        switch result
        case 0x00 { revert(p, size) }
        default { return(p, size) }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 2):

I reckon the version of the compiler is incorrect. This fallback function would compile with earlier versions of solidity only.

I'd probably say that `pragma solidity >0.4.99 <0.6.0;` would work.

**Above version `0.6.0` however**, you would need to make some changes including but not limited to:

- changing `calldatasize` to `calldatasize()` built-in function
- changing `returndatasize` to `returndatasize()` built-in function
- changing `gas` to `gas()` built-in function
- changing `function() payable external {` to `fallback() payable external {`

*Would you mind pasting the code correctly and providing more information? What error message you are getting? That would help me determine the exact problem.*